# VDS.RDF.GraphHandler for skipping Triples

Tags: c#, dotnetrdf

I want to parse only some data out of a ~100 MB rdf [cell line ontology](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/clo/download). So far I am interested in 169.796 out of 1.387.097 tripples (1.217.301 tripples being skipped).

I need ~24 seconds using the handler below to create the graph. This is only some seconds less then parsing the ontology in total.

Is there something I could improve in skipping the tuples I am not interested in?

Thanks!

```
private class MyHandler : VDS.RDF.GraphHandler
    {
        public MyHandler(IGraph g)
            : base(g)
        {
        }

        protected override bool HandleTripleInternal(Triple t)
        {
            if (t.Predicate is UriNode uri 
                && uri.Uri.AbsoluteUri != "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"
                && uri.Uri.AbsoluteUri != "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (t.Object is LiteralNode l && l.Language == "zh")
            {
                return true;
            }
            return base.HandleTripleInternal(t);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the comparison of nodes a bit faster you could try comparing directly with a `UriNode` created from the graph instead of comparing URI strings. If you use the `IGraph.CreateUriNode()` method in your filter constructor to create nodes for `rdfs:subClassOf` and `rdfs:label` and then use `IUriNode.Equals()` as your comparator then you should find that the node comparison can use a faster object reference equality rather than a string comparison.

```
private class MyHandler : GraphHandler
{
    private readonly IUriNode _rdfsSubClassOf;
    private readonly IUriNode _rdfsLabel;

    public MyHandler(IGraph g)
        : base(g)
    {
        _rdfsSubClassOf = g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf"));
        _rdfsLabel = g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label"));
    }

    protected override bool HandleTripleInternal(Triple t)
    {
        if (t.Predicate is UriNode uri
            && !uri.Equals(_rdfsSubClassOf)
            && !uri.Equals(_rdfsLabel))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (t.Object is LiteralNode l && l.Language == "zh")
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.HandleTripleInternal(t);
    }
}
```

However that is only going to speed up the filter and I suspect that if you profile the parse of the file you will find that the majority of the time is spent in parsing the syntax to create the triple that is passed to your filter. There isn't really a way to get around this issue in the dotNetRDF handler architecture.

Comment: Thank you @Kal. I wondered if a other override within the handler might be better suited to do the filtering. I found that this method [Handles Triples by asserting them into the appropriate Graph...](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/T_VDS_RDF_Parsing_Handlers_StoreHandler.htm). Why not filtering bevor asserting Triples into a graph. Is this possible?